# AVPlayerLayer not rendering offline HLS video in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerlayer, avplayerview

I am facing a weird issue in iOS 11. I have an App where I am playing HLS video in AVPlayer. In case of offline HLS video **after starting video audio is playing but video content is not getting rendered on AVPlayerLayer**. This issue is **occurring only in iOS 11 and above**. It is working perfectly in iOS 10. But at the same time online HLS contents are playing perfectly in iOS 11 and iOS 10.

This seems to be a bug in iOS 11 as I checked it in [Apple's sample code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9jmWetG8xxIY3otd296YmQ4Q1k).

I run sample code in iOS 11 device to check.

If it's not a bug in iOS 11 then how to solve this.

Comment: I am as well facing the same issue. I have narrowed it down to an extent. While downloading the video, lowest bitrate stream is getting downloaded, which has only audio tags in the .m3u8 file. Any resolutions?

Comment: @vivin this issue solved with fix in iOS SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This issue is solved now. It was bug in iOS 11.0 but now it's fixed in iOS 11.2.
>
> I used Xcode version 9.2 latest iOS SDK version 11.2

Comment: Could you please share code to play offline using key file saved in user default.

[Optional(Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11863 "See -[AVPlayerItem errorLog] for 1 events" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped, NSUnderlyingError=0x10ccd2590 {Error Domain=CoreMediaErrorDomain Code=-12885 "(null)"}, NSDebugDescription=See -[AVPlayerItem errorLog] for 1 events, NSLocalizedFailureReason=This content is no longer available.})]